# C# RestSharp Library AddHeader Method not work

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
 var cclient = new RestClient("ex.com");
 var reqq = new RestRequest("ex", Method.POST);
 reqq.AddHeader("Cookie", coockie);
 reqq.AddHeader("Host", "profile.callofduty.com");
 reqq.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
 reqq.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
 reqq.AddParameter("username", log);     
 reqq.AddParameter("password", pas);                      
 var responsee = cclient.Post(reqq);
```

but on http debugger when I inspect the request:
[image]

I Don't now the problem please help. none of headers submited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddHeader(key, value)` method is a "proxy" for `AddParameter(key, value, ParameterType.HttpHeader)` method. All your headers are applied to the request and can be found using ordinary debugger if you inspect `Parameters` property of your RestRequest instance (in your code sample it's `reqq`).

Also to send your request you really should use the `Execute(IRestRequest)` method in your RestClient